# How to pass value to html once it is loaded in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to pass a boolean to `ng-hide` in html after it is loaded.

To be more clear

**Example**

*test.html*

```
<div ng-hide="vm.isValueTrue">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
     enabled Networks
  </div>
</div>
```

*test.controller.js*

```
if(condition) {
  vm.isValueTrue = true;
} else vm.isValueTrue = false;

$rootScope.$on('makeTestValueFalse', function() {
vm.isValueTrue = false;
```

---

*test.service.js*

```
if(condition) {
$rootScope.$broadcast('makeTestValueFalse');
}
```

From the above code, what exactly happening is when ever my application is loaded the `test.html` and code from `test.controller.js` is loaded.

Let's say the `if` condition in *test.controller.js* is satisfied and `vm.isValueTrue` is made true. 
So in this case the html will `hide` the div using `ng-hide`.

And due to some operation on the code, the `test.service.js` will be triggered and the `if` condition in the `service.js` will be satisfied and `$rootScope.$broadcast` is triggered and `$rootScope.$on` is called on the `controller.js`

The value is becoming **false** but the html is not able to update as the html is already loaded. I see I can do it with $scope but not exactly clear on how to proceed in this case.

Need help & do let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way to achieve this with a controller and a service broadcasting events as you asked for

Click buttons to show/hide the `div` contents

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.
        module('app')
        .service('myService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            return {
                forceTestValue: function (testValue) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('FORCE_TEST_VALUE', testValue)
                }
            }
        }])
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.testValue = false

            vm.forceTestValue = function (testValue) {
                myService.forceTestValue(testValue)
            }

            $scope.$on('FORCE_TEST_VALUE', function (event, testValue) {
                vm.testValue = testValue
            })
        }])

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="module.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.forceTestValue(true)">
      Force test value to <strong>true</strong>
    </button>
    <button ng-click="vm.forceTestValue(false)">
      Force test value to <strong>false</strong>
    </button>
    <div ng-if="vm.testValue === true">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        enabled Networks
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```